# Reprojecting data from EPSG:3857 into Peru UTM Zone 17

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

I am trying to reproject EPSG:3857 Spherical Mercator OpenStreetMap Data to the local Peruvian UTM Zone 17.

How do I find out which transformation method is suitable for +-1m accuracy?
I have SAFE FME and ArcGIS.

Comment: Please mention what software and version you have available. QGis? ArcGIS?

Comment: What is wrong with [EPSG:32717](https://epsg.io/32717)?

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS, the data will reproject on the fly to match the coordinate system of the data frame. If you need to actually change the projection of the data, use the "[Project](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm)" tool in the GP tools. The tool has useful documentation and in-application help to guide you through the parameters. I usually just pick the first transformation recommended by Esri. It should auto-populate some options.

While FME can technically do this, FME excels at converting data types (which you don't need to do for this) so I recommend sticking to ArcGIS. ArcGIS was built specifically for this task.